# I am learning c and facing an error with vs code in the printf function. I didn't find where I have mistaken. Please help me to resolve it

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
int main (){ 
    int a, b, sum;
    printf("Enter a : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter b : ");
    scanf ("%d", &b );

    sum= a+b;

    printf( "Sum of %d and %d = %d",sum );
    return 0 ;

}
```

This is the output I got but it is not correct. Please tell me where I am wrong ?

```
Enter a: 4
Enter b: 5
Sum of 9 and 6422356 = 4200939
```

I want to get **'b'** (which is the second number) to be printed in the formatted print.
but it is not scanning **'b'** correctly. Why it is scanning **'8'** at the place of **'4'** and **'6422356'** at the place of **'5'**? The output should be **Sum of 4 and 5 = 9.** Tell me what I should do.

When I use `printf( "Sum of a and b = %d",sum );`  instead of `printf( "Sum of %d and %d = %d",sum );` the output is correct

```
Enter a : 4
Enter b : 5
Sum of a and b = 9
```

What is the mistake in the previous code? Have I mistaken in the syntax or what? Why %d is not executing properly?

Comment: `printf( "Sum of %d and %d = %d",sum );` 3 %d's in the format sting need 3 corresponding provided int parameter values. There is only one in your code. You forgot 2. That throws you into undefined behavior, I believe.

Comment: `Why %d is not executing properly?` means `How am I not using %d properly?` Careful about where one places the blame...

Answer (score 2):

The quantity of variables passed to `printf()` does not match the quantity of variables in the *format specifier*

Three versions to remedy your problem:

```
    // print the NAMES of the variables just entered
    printf( "Sum of a and b = %d",sum );

    // print the VALUES of the variables just entered
    printf( "Sum of %d and %d = %d", a, b, sum );

    // or print the NAMES and VALUES of the variables just entered
    printf( "Sum of a(%d) and b(%d) = %d", a, b, sum );
```

You **must** provide a variable (of the right type) for every "%d" (or other formatting specifier) for `printf()` to *match-them-up*

Answer (score 1):

as you have written 3 %d you need 3 different format specifiers respectively add a and b with sum each sepeated woth comma..
Hope it helps